# How to Store Django Logs in a database?

Tags: django, web-applications, logging, django-database

I want to store my application logs (info and not error logs) in database so that further I can use it to display on web.
Please suggest me a good approach.

Comment: Use sentry for that. https://github.com/getsentry/sentry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use  [Sentry](http://sentry.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) and  [Raven](http://raven.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config/django.html)That's the best Approach I bet.

Comment: where do the log files get stored in django?